# Ограничение количества строк memo Delphi XE

Tags: delphi

Есть вот такой код, он ограничивает количество введенных строк в memo. В данном случае не более 5 строк. Все работает отлично.

Как, что бы при копировании с буфера обмена в memo (больше чем 20 строк) - программа автоматически обрезала до 5 строк. То есть если я вставляю 20 строк в memo и стоит ограничение не более 5 строк то программа вставляла только первые 5 строк из буфера.

```
procedure TForm2.Memo1Change(Sender: TObject);
const
  MaxLineCount = 5;
begin
  if Memo1.Lines.Count > MaxLineCount then
    Memo1.Perform(EM_UNDO, 0, 0);
  Memo1.Perform(EM_EMPTYUNDOBUFFER, 0, 0);
end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле вот так:

```
var
  I: integer;
begin
  // Элементы надо удалять с конца, т.к. при удалении из середины,
  // нижние элементы поднимаются чтобы занять места удаленных
  for I := memo1.Lines.Count-1 downto 5 do
    Memo1.Lines.Delete(I);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

Получился такой рабочий вариант:

```
var
  I: integer;
begin
  for I := 5 to memo1.Lines.Count-1 do
  begin
    if i mod 5 = 0 then
      memo1.Lines.Delete(i);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Это очень странный код, вы удаляете не все что больше 5 строк, а каждую 5ю строку ..